# Avoid QTimer to emit timeout signal

Tags: qt, qtimer

I have started Timer to wait for certain condition to be true. IF condition is true then I stop timer and dont want timeout signal to emit or execute connnected slot. But if condition is false within specified time then its allright to emit signal timeout(). But whatever is the case it always emit timeout signal. I have used blockSignals ( true ) as well and it doesnt work. Can some one please advice me.

```
void timerStart( QTimer* timer, int timeMillisecond )
{
  timer = new QTimer( this );
  timer->setInterval( timeMillisecond );
  timer->setSingleShot( true );
  connect( timer, SIGNAL( timeout() ), this, SLOT( noRespFrmServer( ) ) ) ;
  //timer->start( timeMillisecond );
  timer->start();
}
void timerStop( QTimer* timer )
{
  connect( timer, SIGNAL( destroyed( timer ) ), this, SLOT( stopTimerbeforeTimeout( ) ) );
  qDebug() << " we are in timer stop";
  if( timer )
    {
      timer->stop();
      timer->blockSignals( true );
      delete timer;
    }
}
```

Also in timerStop function I have tried to emit destroyed signal but  I got response that it fails to connect.
pLease advice me.

Comment: A couple of things look suspect - in `timerStart()` you ignore the passed parameter `timer`, and don't store your newly created timer, so you have no way to stop it.  Where do you get the timer you pass to `timerStop()`?  Did you perhaps mean to pass `QTimer*&` to `timerStart()`, or to store the timer in a member or (ugh) global?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void timerStart( QTimer* timer, int timeMillisecond )
{
  timer = new QTimer( this );
  timer->setInterval( timeMillisecond );
  timer->setSingleShot( true );
  connect( timer, SIGNAL( timeout() ), this, SLOT( noRespFrmServer( ) ) ) ;
  //timer->start( timeMillisecond );
  timer->start();
}
```

This doesn't actually return the timer you just created. You want something like:

```
QTimer *timerStart(int timeMillisecond )
{
  QTimer* timer = new QTimer( this );
  timer->setInterval( timeMillisecond );
  timer->setSingleShot( true );
  connect( timer, SIGNAL( timeout() ), this, SLOT( noRespFrmServer( ) ) ) ;
  //timer->start( timeMillisecond );
  timer->start();
  return timer;
}
```

Then you can pass the returned timer into the stop function though I suggest you use deleteLater instead of straight up deleting it:

```
void timerStop( QTimer* timer )
{
  qDebug() << " we are in timer stop";
  if( timer )
    {
      qDebug() << " we are stopping the timer";
      timer->stop();
      timer->blockSignals( true );
      timer->deleteLater();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks alot mate  . but it still execute timeout.  I have changed my code but no joy.

Comment: actualluy on debugging I have noticed it doesnt execute "we are stopping timer". I just investigating why.

Comment: Make sure you actually store and pass the timer that got returned from `timerStart`.

Comment: Thanks Mate , i did something silly. It works fine . thanks a lot.